# Session Sharing on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, firefox, microstrategy

I'm using this code on Firefox 57 Web Extension to create a new tab in Firefox 57

```
        let mirror = browser.windows.create({
            url: profiler.url + "?profiler=" + i,
           state: "fullscreen"
        });    

        mirror.then((docking) => { 
        let updateInfo = {
          left : x,
          width : screen.width,
          height : screen.height
        };

        browser.windows.update(docking.id, updateInfo); 
      });
```

This addons will integrated with MicroStartegy Application, but every time I using the code above. The user session will sharing. I means, If one tab logging out, the others tab will log out also. How to avoid this things?

It seem the session at MicroStrategy Application looks at the browser ID. Instead of that, its works well on Chrome because for every tab on Chrome, Chrome will open new application. I've checked on task manager.

So I think the best solution is how to open in Incognito mode.How did i do to open the above code on Incognito Mode?

Or any better idea instead using Incognito Mode?

Any idea would be appreciated.